# Sci-fi book (part of a trilogy); protagonist is the lone of his Builders faction, can control machines

Tags: story-identification, books

The science fiction book I read around 2008 seemed to be the second book of a trilogy. The story was not set on Earth. There were humanoid intelligent beings, ruins of dead civilization, ancient robots, ministries, war with heretics.

The protagonist was the lone representation of a faction or species called Builders. He traveled with a female bodyguard, and could control ancient machines, small and giant.

At the end of the book he gets kidnapped by someone who wants to join the heretics.

Comment: This sounds like _Ancients of Days_ the second book of Confluence by Paul J. McAuley; https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/paul-j-mcauley/ancients-of-days/ if so, then I'll turn this into an answer

Comment: P.S. The first book of this series is _Child of the River_

Comment: That would also be my guess. Confluence is a very good science fantasy series reminescent of Gene Wolfe's "Book of the New Sun".

Comment: Agreed, sounds very much like the Confluence trilogy.

Answer (score 3):

Per multiple comments above, this may be from the *Confluence* series (1997) by Paul J. McAuley. According to the [goodreads.com summary of the combined trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/77339.Confluence), "Builders" and a protagonist who can control ancient machines figure prominently:

> Confluence - a long, narrow, artificial world, half fertile river
>   valley, half crater-strewn desert. A world beyond the end of human
>   history, served by countless machines, inhabited by 10,000 bloodlines
>   who worship their absent creators, riven by a vast war against
>   heretics. This is the home of Yama, found as an infant in a white boat
>   on the world's Great River, raised by an obscure bureaucrat in an
>   obscure town in the middle of a ruined necropolis, destined to become
>   a clerk - until the discovery of his singular ancestry. **For Yama
>   appears to be the last remaining scion of the Builders**, closest of all
>   races to the revered architects of Confluence, **able to awaken and
>   control the secret machineries of the world**. Pursued by enemies who
>   want to make use of his powers, Yama voyages down the length of the
>   world to search for answers to the mysteries of his origin, and to
>   discover if he is to be the saviour of his world, or its nemesis.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. Confluence series indicated in answers is the book I was looking for.